# Installing tmux on Ubuntu from source

Tags: terminal, compile, make, tmux

I've download [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) and am trying to install it on Ubuntu 10.04.

```
$ ./configure 
Configured for Linux
$ make
cc -DBUILD="\"1.3\"" -std=c99 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_POSIX_SOURCE -iquote.   -c -o attributes.o attributes.c
In file included from attributes.c:23:
tmux.h:30:19: error: event.h: No such file or directory
In file included from attributes.c:23:
tmux.h:831: error: field ‘name_timer’ has incomplete type
tmux.h:1025: error: field ‘key_timer’ has incomplete type
tmux.h:1086: error: field ‘event’ has incomplete type
tmux.h:1102: error: field ‘repeat_timer’ has incomplete type
tmux.h:1122: error: field ‘identify_timer’ has incomplete type
tmux.h:1125: error: field ‘message_timer’ has incomplete type
make: *** [attributes.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

event.h is located in the `libevent-dev` package.

```
apt-get install libevent-dev
```

Incidentally, can you use the `tmux` Ubuntu package?

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  The tmux package that comes with Ubuntu is pretty old (1.1 vs. 1.3), and there have been many new features and bug-fixes in the interim.

Comment: this worked great. i wish tmux would add this note on their installation / readme page. i realize they mention libevent but it would be nice if they just did a little ubuntu shout-out.

Answer (score 0):

> tmux.h:30:19: error: event.h: No such file or directory

Use apt to figure out which `*-dev` package contains `event.h`.